# Google Code (Drive) createFile in parent folder/overwrite existing file in parent folder

Tags: google-drive-api, drive

so i created a simple google code that exports sheet to json, and I'm wondering if there's a simple way to:

- 1. Export the file to the same folder where the sheet that script running it is in,
- 2. Overwrite the file if it already exists (also in the same folder the sheet script is in)

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way, but here's how (I assume you're using Apps Script):

1. Get the file id of your spreadsheet https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getId()
2. Get its parent folders - there can be more than one - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getParents()
3. See if there are existing files with the name - there can be more than one - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getFilesByName(String)
4. If it exists set its content https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setcontentcontent
5. If it doesn't exist create it - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#createfilename-content

Comment: thanx for links, will try ASAP

Answer (score 1):

thanx to Ian for research links, made it work :)

here's the snippet if anyone else is needing the same thing

```
  var _ID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
  var _sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var _file = DriveApp.getFolderById(_ID);
  var _folder = _file.getParents().next();  
  var _parentFolder = _file.getParents().next();
  var _existingJsons = _parentFolder.getFilesByName(sheet.getName()+".json");

  // if .json with the same name already exists in this directory, just overwrite content
  if (_existingJsons.hasNext()){
    while (_existingJsons.hasNext() ){
      var _json = _existingJsons.next();
      _json.setContent(output);
      Logger.log(_json.getName());
    }
  } 
  // if not, create new one, and move it in the same folder sheet is in
  else {
    var _json = DriveApp.createFile(sheet.getName()+".json", output, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT);
    _json.makeCopy(_parentFolder);
    _json.setTrashed(true);
  }
```